# Photoswipe and Infinite AJAX Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll, photoswipe

First up, apologies for lots of code. Just don't want to miss anything.

I am generating images on a page in this format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- photoswipe Core CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/photoswipe/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css"> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="page">  
      <div id="thumbs" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
        <ul class="responsive-thumbnails" data-max-width="202px" data-padding="4px">
          <li class="thumb">
            <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
              <a href="img/pv_31.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x800"><img src="img/th_31.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="" /></a>
            </figure>
          </li>

          <!-- multiple of <li> as above here for each thumbnail image -->

        </ul>
      </div>

    <div id="pagination"><!-- my codeigniter paginiation output (gets hidden by infintie scroll</div>   

    </div>

    <!-- Infinite AJAX Scroll stuff --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ias = $.ias({
      container: "#thumbs",
      item: ".thumb",
      pagination: "#pagination",
      next: ".next a"
    });

    ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
    ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({offset: 5}));
    ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({text: 'There are no more pages left to load.'}));
/*    //I think somehow here, I need to trigger photoswipe to add new items after IAS has added more. 
    ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
          lightBox.init();
        );
      });
*/
     </script>

     <!-- Root element of PhotoSwipe. Must have class pswp. -->
     <div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
     <!-- this is where the standard photoswipe html elements are stored. Copied from their docs. Omitted here -->
     </div> 

     <!-- photoswipe Core JS file -->
     <script src="assets/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.min.js"></script> 
     <script src="assets/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js"></script> 
     <!-- my script to initiate Photoswipe instance (see below) -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/photoswipe.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Contents of photoswipe.js:

```
(function($) {
    var $pswp = $('.pswp')[0];
    var image = [];

  $('#thumbs').each( function() {
  var $pic = $(this),
    getItems = function() {
      var items = [];
      $pic.find('a').each(function() {
        var $href   = $(this).attr('href'),
        $size   = $(this).data('size').split('x'),
        $width  = $size[0],
        $height = $size[1];

        var item = {
          src : $href,
          w   : $width,
          h   : $height
        }

        items.push(item);
      });

      return items;
    }

    var items = getItems();

    console.log(items);

    $.each(items, function(index, value) {
        image[index]     = new Image();
        image[index].src = value['src'];
      });

    $pic.on('click', 'li', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $index = $(this).index();
        var options = {
            index: $index,
            bgOpacity: 0.7,
            showHideOpacity: true,
            showAnimationDuration: 500,
            hideAnimationDuration: 500
        }

        var lightBox = new PhotoSwipe($pswp, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        lightBox.init();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Photoswipe is working, but it only works with the first batch of photo initially loaded on the page. In this case I load 20. Any more images that get appended by IAS can be clicked on and do bring up the photoswipe lightbox, but their preview sized images are not showing in the lightbox. I just get the first 20 to scroll through.

So the question is, how do I get photoswipe and Infinite AJAX Scroll to work together?